# Using media query or using the visible classes from Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question about bootstrap.

So basically, depending on the device, I want to show a different image. Using media queries, I was the changing the content of the  depending on the device's size.

However, I just learned about the visible classes in bootstrap, and I tried them out, and they gave the same result, except that all images are loaded, and they are hidden. So I was wondering: which method is more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the first method is more efficient because you only load the image that you need based on the device size. It would decrease the number of outgoing requests and allow faster initial page load.

Comment: +1 Decreasing the amount of content downloaded is important on mobile. I would do whatever route has the smaller payload.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that logically, this would be the best method, but I wasn't sure. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Certainy the Bootstrap classes because it's faster mobile-friendly development. These can be used for showing and hiding content by device via media query, combined with large, small, and medium devices.

They make developers work more simple and simple and the feasibility to hide excess of ifo in smaller devices and vice versa

Comment: Well, it may be faster to use the classes (when coding), but especially in mobile, having the device load a lot of hidden images, it's a heavy burden and the user may just give up loading the page... (btw I didn't downvote your answer: it's not efficient for user's navigation, but it may save you some time when coding...)

Comment: Downloading more content that won't be visible is a bad idea on mobile. It takes longer to load the page for no reason, and uses more data that customers may be paying for.